# The existing published deployment does not appear to be a valid deployment manifest

Tags: wpf, clickonce, publish

So I was able to publish my wpf application using click once without any problem for a couple of months. But yesterday when I tried I got an odd looking message.

[image: Error message]

When choosing Yes option the publish stops and fills error list with those errors:

[image]

I tried searching online but without any success.

Comment: For the first look it seems to be an ftp server problem.

Comment: I doubt it. I started having this problem after upgrading VS2019 to 16.7.3. (I also checked the deployment manifest, and it's fine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue started happening to me after I upgraded to **Visual Studio 2019 16.7.3**. I also updated my application from **.NET Framework 4.7.2** to **4.8**. (Although I doubt that's the issue, I did not revert to 4.7.2 to test it.)

My solution was to publish to a local folder and then upload those files with a separate FTP application (*e.g.,* [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)). Upgrading my existing ClickOnce app worked fine.

Details: In your application's *Properties* page, select the *Publish* tab. Change the **Publishing Folder Location** field from "`ftp://whatever`" to "`C:\publish-MyApp`." Click the *Publish Now* button. VS will create the files pretty quickly. Next, use your FTP application to upload the contents of the `C:\publish-MyApp` folder to the existing installation folder on your server. This overwrites the existing `setup.exe` and `MyApp.application` files and adds a new folder (*e.g.,* `MyApp_1.2.3.4`) in the `Application Files` folder.

(One side benefit of this method is that it's faster to publish because **FileZilla** is a lot faster at uploading than Visual Studio.)

Comment: Yep that's what I did. I had to use separate FTP app. But I don't remember upgrading Visual Studio so I don't think this is the case. My current Visual Studio version is 16.4.5 but I do have 4.8 .Net Framework version I noticed.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by unchecking the passive mode check box when prompted for the ftp credentials

Comment: So simple. Fixed the issue for me after lots of trouble.