# ftp publish vs folder publish and upload with FTP program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publishing

I have a web project in my case an Umbraco project.
When i try to publish the website with VS2019, i have to use the FTP publish method.
This works, but takes a long time.

I tried to publish the project to a folder (locally it works with IIS) but when i copy those files with an FTP client (WinSCP, FileZilla) to the server the website does not work. or partly works, What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Did you check the access-rights? They may be different when coping/publishing

Comment: Look at this [Publish to a local folder and then upload its contents using an FTP client.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593593/the-existing-published-deployment-does-not-appear-to-be-a-valid-deployment-manif) Does this help? Did you copy into the wrong folder?